# ASP.NET Session timing out early

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

I have seen the other questions like me, but they aren't exactly like mine. I am using the standard ASP.NET authentication via the following entry in the web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="3600" />
</authentication>
```

login.aspx.cs

```
accountID = myReader["AccountID"].ToString();
Session["AccountID"] = accountID;
```

I tested this with the value of 1 and 5 and it worked like it should. Set it to 3600 and left for a half hour, and it expired and redirected me to login when I reloaded the page. I read about the IIS session state settings. I disabled those before I tried 1 min and 5 min and it seemed to work. Just doesn't work for a long interval. Originally IIS was set to in process, and mode was use cookies and timeout was 20 min. Changed it to 3600 to match web.config and it timed out too early. Disabled it and it works for short intervals, seemingly somewhere less than 30 min.

When I change these settings in IIS, do I need to do an IIS reset? So is this setting still at 20 min when I think it's disabled? That almost seems like that is how it is behaving.

Comment: session timeout is derived from  <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="20">; change timeout value to 60 and try

Comment: I think you are confusing ASP.NET forms authentication and ASP.NET Sessions. Those are quite different notions.

Comment: both correct comments. I hired someone to create the auth system and login because I didn't have time to look into it myself. Not sure they did it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your timeout value in Forms tag and add Session time out in Web.config

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Do I need all of that or will something like this work?  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="3600" />

Comment: it should work; timeout value in sessionState is in minutes

Comment: ok thanks. unfortunately it takes a little time to test. I think it will work and i'll mark your answer when it does.

Comment: just tested it and it appears to work! It at least seemed to break that seeming 20 min threshold. I think that since the timeout was in the wrong place, perhaps the IIS tried to handle the timeout in some default manner. That's all I can think.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that anyone is checking this and can't work out why they've followed the instructions above but it still times out on early in other environments - you may want to check to see that the load balancer isn't switching to a differet node before the session expires.